# Javascript push array column to an one dimention array

Tags: javascript

I would like to push the age attribute from items to an ages array
f.e.

```
items =[{name : "asd", age : "23"},
        {name : "asd2", age : "34"}]
```

to an array:

```
ages = [ 23,34]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with angular. It's a pure (and quite basic, TBH) JavaScript question. If you can't do that yet, I suggest you learn the basics first (loops, arrays, etc.) before touching Angular, which is quite a complex beast.

Answer (score 2):

If you got it right then you can use `.map` to get all the values corresponding to key age.

```js
var items =[{name: "asd", age: "23"}, {name: "asd2", age: "34"}];

var data = items.map(({age}) => age);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: I am sure you are intuitive enough to answer these questions by yourself.

Comment: @CapBaracudas Nobody should be punished like this because they don't want to remove their (correct) answer. At least think of an explanation. This is low.